# Can't set screen lock to other than 'Slide'

Tags: lock-screens

I can't switch the screen lock mode to anything other than 'Slide'. Other options (None, PIN, Password, Pattern, Face) **are** available, but after setting up any of them the label with the selected option keeps showing 'Slide', and indeed nothing changes in the lock screen.

My device is a Xperia SP (C5303). I'm running a stock ROM (12.1.A.1.205) with Android 4.3 which I recently flashed; previously I was running CyanogenMod with KitKat. I *didn't* wipe user data when flashing.

Looking for solutions to similar problems, I have already tried disabling device administrators; and I couldn't try "Clear credentials" since it was greyed out. Clearing the data for the Xperia Screen Lock app (com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.uxpnxt) doesn't make any difference.

Anything else I could try before wiping all user data?